# UrbanAirship iOS AirshipConfig.plist file is missing

Tags: ios, push-notification, plist, urbanairship.com

I am trying to integrate UrbanAiship push notifications with my iOS app.
I have followed the documentation and created a AirshipConfig.plist file and populated the fields with my app Key and secret, but every time I run the app I get the following error:

```
[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 150] The AirshipConfig.plist file is missing and no application credentials were specified at runtime.
```

Again, I created the AirshipConfig.plist file and put it in the root folder of my app, I do not understand why it is not finding the file??

I also tried to define the key and secret at run time like this:

```
UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];

// You can also programmatically override the plist values:
config.inProduction = true;
config.developmentAppKey = @"wwgwJYJm...yFQ ";
config.developmentAppSecret = @"_C5nN...j4gA";
```

and even though I check the key and secret 1000x against the codes under Settings > API Keys on go.urbanairship.com I get the following error:

```
[UAConfig validate] [Line 168] Current App Key (wwgwJYJm...yFQ ) is not valid.
```

Again i have checked, checked again, and re-checked that the app key matches the app settings and I dont understand why I am getting this error?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: How do you add AirshipConfig.plist to your project? You need to right click on project in Xcode -> Add files to "MyApp" -> select AirshipConfig.plist, check "Copy items into destinations groups folder " and you need to be sure, that you select a right target in "Add target" cell. Hope this helps

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but assuming you have copy/pasted your code, you have a space after your App Key:  config.developmentAppKey = @"wwgwJYJm...yFQ ";

Comment: @dperconti you saved me! cannot believe I missed that :/ I guess i was in need of the weekend! thanks again